# Docusign: REST Api: Create Envelope with Signers' order

Tags: docusignapi

Here is my problem with creating envelope with signers’ order.

If I create the envelope using `Docusign` console and enabling ***Set signing order*** like this:

[image: Set signing order in Docusign console]

Then the pdf will be sent to the second signer like this which is OK:

[image: Tabs shown to the second signer]

**BUT,**

If I create the envelope by REST API call like this:

[image: Set signing order in Request JSON]

Then the pdf will be sent to the second signer like below and the second signer cannot see his signhere or text tabs:

[image: Tabs shown to the second signer]

Would you please advise how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the tabs in your code. But using the API, when you add the tabs, you have to make sure they match the correct recipientID and correct routingOrder.
How did you add the tabs? please provide JSON/code for that, the issue is in there.